# PrintWriter and PrintStream methods?

Tags: java, c++, scjp

PrintStream

1. `write()` overloaded methods of PrintStream
2. `print()` overloaded methods of PrintStream

PrintWriter

1. `write()` overloaded methods of PrintWriter
2. `print()` overloaded methods of PrintWriter

I don't understand that if both write() method and print() method doing the same thing (writing to file) then why this two name is defined in those classes ?

Answer (score 1):

`print()` formats the output, while `write()` just prints the characters it is given. `print()` handles many argument types, converting them into printable strings of characters with `String.valueOf()`, while `write()` just handles single characters, arrays of characters, and strings.

To illustrate the difference, `write(int)` interprets the argument as a single character to be printed, while `print(int)` converts the integer into a character string.

`write(49)` prints:

> 1

`print(49)` prints:

> 49